# CloseableHttpClient connection pool shut down

Tags: java, httpclient

when I use CloseableHttpClient and do excute method , it works normally at the first time but never successed after . 
it will throw exception which said "Connection pool shut down"

someone said it because I haven't close the client 
someone said is a bug in httpclient 4.3

my project doesn't exist the issue above ,but it still doesn't work will

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientManagerUtils.getHttpClient();

    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
            log.info("调用网易接口成功,url:{},param:{}", url, JSONObject.toJSON(param));
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity.getContentType().toString().contains("application/json")) {
                String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "utf-8");
                return JSON.toJavaObject(JSON.parseObject(responseString), NimResult.class);
            }
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("http code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() + ", exception:" +
                    EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("调用网易接口异常,url:{},param:{}", url, JSONObject.toJSON(param), e);
    } finally {
        httpClient.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I shouldn't close the client , but should close the response instead. the client will close automaly since httpclient 4.4
I have resolved it :)